# GROUP BY max in mysql

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following two entries:

```
`id`     |    `timestamp`   |   `content`   |  `reference`
 1       |     2012-01-01   |    NEWER      |   1
 2       |     2013-01-01   |    NEWEST     |   1
 3       |     2011-01-01   |    OLD        |   2
```

I need the following result from my query:

```
`id`     |    `timestamp`   |   `content`   |  `reference`
 2       |     2013-01-01   |    NEWEST     |   1
 3       |     2011-01-01   |    OLD        |   2
```

Here's what I have so far, but it is incorrect:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY reference
```

What would be the correct query here?

I am looking to get the newest piece of `content` per reference id. In the example above, there are two reference id's (1 & 2), and I want to get the most recent entry for each.

Comment: Can you describe with words what you are expecting. It's not obvious with your data sample.

Comment: If you can put your schema and test data on SQLFiddle (for all questions like this) that would be very helpful for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp desc) as sub
GROUP BY reference
```

If you wish to expand the query, put limiting logic into the subquery like so for better performance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM table 
      WHERE 1=1 and 2=2
      ORDER BY timestamp desc
     ) as sub
GROUP BY reference
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does putting in `WHERE 1=1 AND 2=2` make the query more efficient?

Comment: Also, does you query perform better than doing an `IN` (like the two other answers)? If so, why?

Comment: I am not suggesting you use `1=1` but if you were to limit the results using `where content='old'` that where would belong in the inner query. Nested queries and `IN` statements have about the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want the newest of each reference? Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY timestamp DESC GROUP BY reference LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Gah, that's not going to work - `id` is not part of a `GROUP BY` in the subselect. No time to look into further, but hope it gives you ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where reference_id in 
    (select max(id) from table group by reference)
```